# Sets of classifiers and their risk

Tags: machine-learning, classification

$$ Fa = \{f_w(x) =< w, x > +w0, w ∈ Rd \} $$
$$ Fb = \{f_i,θ(x) = 2 × {\mathbb{1}}x_i >θ − 1, i ∈ [1, d], θ ∈ R \} $$
$$ Fc = \{f_µ,_r(x) = 2 × 1||x−µ||2<r − 1, µ ∈ R
d
, r ∈ R \} $$

$$Fe = \{f_w,_{w0}(x) =< x, w > + < w0
, x >, w, w0 ∈ R
d \}$$

Here are 4 families of classifiers. I am suppose to identify their ability of overfitting and I have no idea on how to do it. I should classify them by the their risk of overfitting.

What whould I look for ?

Comment: A good start would be to explain your problem - what are the inputs, outputs, parameters, what is the meaning of your notations, etc.